# How to solve the liar problem?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

In an island live two kinds of people: liar and truth-teller, the former only tells lies and the latter only tells truth, now there're two men **A** and **B** from the island, A said: "B is a truth-teller." B said: "We two are different kinds of people." Please identify the sort of them.

If we mark **A** with `a` and **B** with `b` and use `True` to represent truth-teller, the answer is apparently `b == False && a == False` . This seems to be easy to translate into mathematica code, I first tried:

```
Reduce[{Refine[a, b == True] == False, Refine[b, a == True] == True}]
(* b == True && a == False *)
```

…What's this? Maybe I have some misunderstandings for the Functions… I didn't think much and tried another approach:

```
Reduce[{Implies[b == True, a == ! b], Implies[a == True, b == True]}, {a, b}]
(* (a == False && b == True) || (a - True) (-b + True) != 0 *)
```

…What's this? Maybe I have some misunderstandings for the Functions… I didn't think much and tried my third approach:

```
Reduce[{If[b == True, a == ! b, a == b], If[a == True, b == True, b == False]}]
(*b == False && a == False && False - True != 0*)
```

…This time I get the right answer, but what's `False - True != 0`!? `Reduce` doesn't know booleans?

Surely I'm not solving the problem in the right way, how to get the answer properly with mma? And I would be appreciate if you can tell me where I'm wrong in the first two samples.

---

…I forgot a important thing: in logic, if $p$ is false and $q$ is true, then $p\Rightarrow q$ is still true, so my first two translations for the liar problem is incomplete and the third one is correct because I unconsciously add the missing rule in `If`, so my second sample should be modified to:

```
Reduce[Implies[b == True, a == ! b] && 
       Implies[b == False, a == b] && 
       Implies[a == True, b == True] && 
       Implies[a == False, b == False], {a, b}]
(* 
   (a == False && b == False && False - True != 0) || 
   (a - False) (-b + False) (a - True) (b - True) != 0 
 *)
```

Though the result is still a little strange, at least this time the right answer is involved in it, and together with the comment from @Daniel Lichtblau it's not that unacceptable now.

And of course the answer from @halirutan using `!Xor` is terser.

And had I noticed the correct syntax for `SatisfiabilityInstances` earlier,  perhaps I would have lost my curiosity and this question wouldn't exist anymore…:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[Implies[b == True, a == ! b] && 
                        Implies[b == False, a == b] && 
                        Implies[a == True, b == True] && 
                        Implies[a == False, b == False], {a, b}]
(* {{False, False}} *)

SatisfiabilityInstances[If[b == True, a == ! b, a == b] && 
                        If[a == True, b == True, b == False], {a, b}]
(* {{False, False}} *)
```

However, I'm still unable to give a good explanation for my first sample: as we've seen, it gives an answer similar to the second sample, but:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[Refine[a, b == True] == ! b && 
                        Refine[a, b == False] == b && 
                        Refine[b, a == True] == True && 
                        Refine[b, a == False] == False, {a, b}] 
(* {} *)
```

…Why?

---

…I get the truth: `Refine` is not available for the logical judgement，and the "right" answer for the first sample is just a illusion, that's just because `a` and `b` don't have a explicit relationship so the assumption inside `Refine` is considered as something meaningless by `Reduce`, the process is similar to:

```
Reduce[{Refine[a, b == 3] == 1, Refine[b, a == 4] == 2}]
(* b == 2 && a == 1 *)
```

OK, now it's all clear 囧.

Comment: In the Booleans, you can always replace `b == True` with just `b`, and `If[a, b, !b]` with `a == b`. So then you can do `Solve[{a == b, b == (a != b)}]` and get `{{b -> False, a -> False}}`. I'm not familiar with the other functions you used, but surely someone more knowledgeable will come along and explain why they don't work.

Comment: @RahulNarain Hehe, I'm unfamiliar with them, too. In fact it's the first time I use `Refine` and `Implies` in my code.

Comment: Reduce is not readily able to handle booleans as such. You can convert to algebraic equations in Z_2 if you want to go that route. Or else use the nice methods indicated by Halirutan. I'd probably go that latter route myself.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Er…what does **Z_2** mean?

Comment: @xzczd I don't understand, what you tried to express with e.g. `Refine[b, a == False]`. `Refine` transforms, hopefully simplifies, an expression if you know that some assumption holds. What do you know about some unknown `b` when `a==False` holds? Plus, `Refine` is not the right tool for boolean functions. Have you checked the help-page?

Comment: @halirutan Of course I`ve read it :) and with those examples in the document, what puzzles me is why the last sample didn't work while the first one seems……………OH!!! I understand, I'll edit my question again, wait for a moment.

Comment: Various notations: Z_2 == Z/<2> == GF[2] == finite field comprised of {0,1}.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you seen, that *Mathematica* is capable of many [boolean computations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/BooleanComputation.html) using special boolean functions? Let's assume someone from the island makes a statement, then when the statement is true, whether or not he tells the statement is true, depends on whether or not he is a truth-teller. When we know, which kind he is, we know the correct statement through *what he says*. Therefore, let's define a function for this and check the truth-table

```
trueStatement[statement_,isTruthTeller_]:=!Xor[statement,isTruthTeller]    
BooleanTable[{a,b,trueStatement[a,b]},{a,b}]//TableForm
(*
True    True    True
True    False   False
False   True    False
False   False   True
*)
```

So, if A says a statement is true and A is a truth-teller, the statement is true for sure. On the other hand, if A is not a truth-teller, then the real statement is false.

Now we want to transform the two statements

> A said: "B is a truth-teller." B said: "We two are different kinds of people."

without knowing whether `a` or `b` are liars or truth-tellers

```
eq = trueStatement[b, a] && trueStatement[a == ! b, b]
```

The statements read as: `a` says that `b` is a truth-teller **and** `b` says, that `a` is not of the same kind as `b`. Now we can simply do

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[eq, {a, b}]

(* {{False, False}} *)
```

Therefore, both, `a` and `b` are liars.

Comment: Well…in fact I've already tried `SatisfiabilityInstances` but failed, because I didn't notice that we can combine equations with either `&&` or `{}` in `Solve` and `Reduce` while only `&&` is available for `SatisfiabilityInstances`囧. Also, I notice the mistake in my original analysis, see my edit of the question for more details.

Answer (score 8):

```
Cases[Tuples[{True, False}, 2], {a_, b_} /; 
  Equivalent[a, b] && Equivalent[b, Xor[a, b]]]

(*{{False, False}}*)

FindInstance[Equivalent[a, b] && Equivalent[b, Xor[a, b]], {a, b}, Booleans]

(*{{a -> False, b -> False}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Proposition a : A is a truth - teller,

Proposition b : B is a truth - teller

A said : "B is a truth-teller."
We observe:
a True iff b True

Hence :

a [Equivalent] b is a tautology.

B said : "We two are different kinds of people."

We observe
b True iff the above proposition is True .

Hence :

b [Equivalent] (a [Xor] b) is a tautology.

Solution :

FindInstance[{a [Equivalent] b, b [Equivalent] (a [Xor] b) }, {a,
b}, Booleans ]

{{a -> False, b -> False}}

Conclusion: Both A and B are liars.

Comment: Well, this solution is already provided [by chyanog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26617/1871).