# How can I use Mathematica to solve a complex truth-teller/liar logic problem?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

I have a logic puzzle I want to convert to Mathematica to solve:

Person A states, "Exactly two people are truth-tellers,"
Person B states, "I and Person C are truth-tellers."
Person C states, "Person A is a liar or Person B is a liar." (here this is a use of inclusive or)
Each person is either a truth-teller or a liar.
The full first-order logic formulation of this is as follows:

- $A↔[(A∧B∧¬C)∨(A∧¬B∧C)∨(¬A∧B∧C)]$
- $B↔(B∧C)$
- $C↔(¬A∨¬B)$

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to create a truth table in Mathematica for this problem and/or solve using Mathematica's logic functions for who is a truth-teller and who is a liar. I tried using Boolean Table but couldn't get the right input. How can I use the solving features in Mathematica to input logical statements and figure out who is telling the truth and who is lying?
For a helpful similiar problem, see [How to solve the liar problem?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14051/how-to-solve-the-liar-problem)

Comment: The last statement is a bit ambiguous, and could instead be interpreted as C↔[(¬A∧B)∨(A∧¬B)] (i.e., exactly one of A and B are liars.)  Note that as you've interpreted it, the status of A is undetermined, as Mathematica found below;  under this other interpretation, A must be a truth-teller.

Comment: I was trying to determine if there is enough information to determine who is a liar and who is a truth-teller using Mathematica. The logical statement by Person C is not Xor and instead just normal Or. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can enter the logic formulations into *Mathematica* like this — Copy & paste the following code, and you can see the symbols.

```
p = a \[Equivalent] ((a \[And] 
       b \[And] \[Not] c) \[Or] (a \[And] \[Not] b \[And] 
       c) \[Or] (\[Not] a \[And] b \[And] c));
q = b \[Equivalent] (b \[And] c);
r = c \[Equivalent] (\[Not] a \[Or] \[Not] b);
```

1. **We prefer lowercase variables**, since some uppercase variables have special meanings (e.g., `E` for constant $e$, `N` for numerical value function).
2. Most symbols (in the form of `\[...]` as you see) have shortcuts to type and have built-in meanings. *For example*, `a \[Equivalent] b` can be typed with `a` `Esc` `equiv` `Esc` `b`, and it's just a more human-readable form of `Equivalent[a, b]` internally. That is, there's not any difference from:

   ```
   p = Equivalent[a, (a && b && !c) || (a && !b && c) || (!a && b && c)]; 
   q = Equivalent[b, b && c]; 
   r = Equivalent[c, !a || !b];
   ```

Then you can use any of the following commands to get the result:

```
p \[And] q \[And] r // BooleanConvert
p \[And] q \[And] r // LogicalExpand
p \[And] q \[And] r // FullSimplify
```

```
! b && c
```

Hence $P\land Q\land R\equiv\lnot B\land C$, indicating B must be a liar and C must be a truth-teller. Truth table can be generated with:

```
TableForm[BooleanTable[{a, b, c, p \[And] q \[And] r}, {a, b, c}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"A", "B", "C", "P\[And]Q\[And]R"}}]
```

Comment: Note that the result does not include $A$, which implies that $A$'s status as a truth-teller or liar is not determined by the logical statements given.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes. This indicates that, from what they say, nothing can be inferred about A.

Comment: You can also use `SatisfiabilityInstances[p \[And] q \[And] r, {a, b, c}]` to find a solution to the problem and `SatisfiabilityInstances[p \[And] q \[And] r, {a, b, c}, All]` to find all of them.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer already provided a great solution. Alternatively, you can try:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[(a \[Equivalent] ((a \[And] 
        b \[And] \[Not] c) \[Or] (a \[And] \[Not] b \[And] 
        c) \[Or] (\[Not] a \[And] b \[And] 
        c))) && (b \[Equivalent] (b \[And] 
      c)) && (c \[Equivalent] (\[Not] a \[Or] \[Not] b)), {a, b, c}]
```

[image]